# How can I find all annotated fields in nested DTO?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I'm trying to find all annotated fields in Kotlin.
Is there any neat way to solve this problem?

I want to get annotated field name, "value" from Parent class

```kotlin
data class Parent(
    val nested: Nested
)

data class Nested(
    @CustomAnnotation
    val value: String
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather unclear:

- "find all annotated **fields**" vs "I want to get annotated **field name**"
- Is there more than one annotation classes involved?
- Are there data classes nested more than one level deep?
- Since you know the classes, why access the annotation of a nested class through a possible parent class?

Still, to give you an idea on how to get the names of the fields and its annotation names in a Map:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass
import kotlin.reflect.full.*
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.jvmErasure

fun KClass<*>.getFieldAndAnnotationNames(): Map<String, List<String>> {
  return declaredMemberProperties
    .filter { it.annotations.isNotEmpty() }
    .associate { kProp ->
      kProp.name to kProp.annotations.map {
        it.toString().substringAfterLast("$")
      }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
annotation class CustomAnnotation

@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
annotation class CustomAnnotation2

data class Nested(
  @CustomAnnotation val nestedValue1: String,
  val nestedValue2: Double
)

data class Parent(
  val parentValue1: Nested,
  @CustomAnnotation @CustomAnnotation2 val parentValue2: String
)

Parent::class.getFieldAndAnnotationNames().forEach(::println)
// Output: parentValue2=[CustomAnnotation(), CustomAnnotation2()]

Nested::class.getFieldAndAnnotationNames().forEach(::println)
// Output: nestedValue1=[CustomAnnotation()]
```

And this is another function using above function to get info about all nested data classes and its annotations:

```
fun KClass<*>.getNestedFieldAndAnnotationNames(): Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> {
  return declaredMemberProperties
    .filter { it.returnType.jvmErasure.isData }
    .associate { kProp ->
      kProp.name to kProp.returnType.jvmErasure.getFieldAndAnnotationNames()
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Parent::class.getNestedFieldAndAnnotationNames().forEach(::println)
// Output: parentValue1={nestedValue1=[CustomAnnotation()]}
```